# Time Complexity - Big O

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I am attempting to solve the following algorithms time complexity:

```
s = 0;
i = 1;
while (s < n) {
  s = s + i;
  i = i + 1;
}
```

However, I am having trouble determining which power the logarithm's base is in the while loop.

I know it will iterate through the while loop 3 times for `n=5` and 10 times for `n=50` but how can you determine big oh from this?

Comment: You are adding 1+2+3+4+5+... which is x(x+1)/2 .  So if n>x(x+1)/2 then because of the quadratic formula x=sqrt(2n) .  So the time complxity is O( sqrt(n) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity is `O(Sqrt(2n))`.

Let's assume that `s=s+i` and `i=i+1` take a single unit of time, so the question is: given `n`, what is the number `i` (i.e. number of `while` loops)?

Let's look at the value of s for each iteration:

```
iteration value of s
1         s+1
2         s+1+2
3         s+1+2+3
4         s+1+2+3+4
```

So clearly, after `i` iterations, the value of `s` is the sum of 1..i, which is i*(i+1)/2.

Since `s<=n`, then `i*(i+1)/2<=n` and so `i~Sqrt(2n)`.

**EDIT**

A simple C# code to see the above:

```
int iterate(int n)
{
    int s = 0;
    int i = 1;
    while (s < n)
    {
        s = s + i;
        i = i + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("s: {0}, i: {1} (Sqrt(2s): {2})",s,i,Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(2*s)));
    }
    return i;
}

void Main()
{
    iterate(1000);
}
```

produces following table (see that the number `i` matches our `Sqrt(2s)`):

```
s: 1, i: 2 (Sqrt(2s): 2)
s: 3, i: 3 (Sqrt(2s): 3)
s: 6, i: 4 (Sqrt(2s): 4)
s: 10, i: 5 (Sqrt(2s): 5)
s: 15, i: 6 (Sqrt(2s): 6)
s: 21, i: 7 (Sqrt(2s): 7)
s: 28, i: 8 (Sqrt(2s): 8)
s: 36, i: 9 (Sqrt(2s): 9)
s: 45, i: 10 (Sqrt(2s): 10)
s: 55, i: 11 (Sqrt(2s): 11)
s: 66, i: 12 (Sqrt(2s): 12)
s: 78, i: 13 (Sqrt(2s): 13)
s: 91, i: 14 (Sqrt(2s): 14)
s: 105, i: 15 (Sqrt(2s): 15)
s: 120, i: 16 (Sqrt(2s): 16)
s: 136, i: 17 (Sqrt(2s): 17)
s: 153, i: 18 (Sqrt(2s): 18)
s: 171, i: 19 (Sqrt(2s): 19)
s: 190, i: 20 (Sqrt(2s): 20)
s: 210, i: 21 (Sqrt(2s): 21)
s: 231, i: 22 (Sqrt(2s): 22)
s: 253, i: 23 (Sqrt(2s): 23)
s: 276, i: 24 (Sqrt(2s): 24)
s: 300, i: 25 (Sqrt(2s): 25)
s: 325, i: 26 (Sqrt(2s): 26)
s: 351, i: 27 (Sqrt(2s): 27)
s: 378, i: 28 (Sqrt(2s): 28)
s: 406, i: 29 (Sqrt(2s): 29)
s: 435, i: 30 (Sqrt(2s): 30)
s: 465, i: 31 (Sqrt(2s): 31)
s: 496, i: 32 (Sqrt(2s): 32)
s: 528, i: 33 (Sqrt(2s): 33)
s: 561, i: 34 (Sqrt(2s): 34)
s: 595, i: 35 (Sqrt(2s): 35)
s: 630, i: 36 (Sqrt(2s): 36)
s: 666, i: 37 (Sqrt(2s): 37)
s: 703, i: 38 (Sqrt(2s): 38)
s: 741, i: 39 (Sqrt(2s): 39)
s: 780, i: 40 (Sqrt(2s): 40)
s: 820, i: 41 (Sqrt(2s): 41)
s: 861, i: 42 (Sqrt(2s): 42)
s: 903, i: 43 (Sqrt(2s): 43)
s: 946, i: 44 (Sqrt(2s): 44)
s: 990, i: 45 (Sqrt(2s): 45)
s: 1035, i: 46 (Sqrt(2s): 46)
```

Comment: Great explanation, and fantastic C program to show concrete proof sqrt(2n) works, this has eliminated my confusion about addition/division in while loops time complexity.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Don't constant factors normally get left out of big O notations so O(sqrt(2n)) = O(sqrt(n))  ?

Comment: Yes, technically yes. The `n` really refers to the `n` in the script. If it was `m`, I'd have said that the complexity is `O(Sqrt(2m))`, i.e. in the usual notation it is `O(Sqrt(n))`.